# Nouns used with particles

Tags: adverbs

I saw 'way back,' 'way up' 'way down' 'way out' kind of things. Then can I say 'road in,' 'door out' and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**way out** is usually used to mark the route to the exit. **[way](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/way)** is an abstract concept, not a real thing. It could be a doorway, a corridor, a path, a stair, or any combination other these things.

**road** and **door** are real things: you can see that a door is a door, a road is a road etc, so the is no need to include the word **door** on a sign that is attached to a door.

This [NGram Graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20way%20out%2Cthe%20door%20out%2C%20the%20road%20out&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20way%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20door%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20road%20out%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20way%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20door%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20road%20out%3B%2Cc0) shows that **the way out** is quite common in written English, but the very small number of instances of **the door out** are not really the same usage. Here is a typical example:

> A gust of wind almost pulled the **door out** of my grasp

Some of the instances of **the road out** are real:

> All along **the road out**, the Chinese were hitting the slow-moving column of marines that were fighting for their lives. -*Frozen Chosin (Korea): The March Out*